# Traverse through an index variable backwards, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I have a very simple piece of code in Python 2.7 where I must use a `while loop` to traverse an index backwards. I am getting a print out where it goes backwards, but my `while loop` does not stop at the end and therefore produces an out of range error and I do not know why. I am trying to dope it out but failing.

Here is my code:

```
fruit = 'banana'
print len(fruit)

index = 0
while index <= len(fruit):
    letter = fruit[index - 1]
    print letter
    index = index - 1
```

What I think is going on here is I am initializing the var `index` to `0` and then asking python to work with the var `fruit` while the index is less than or equal to the size of fruit. The problem is when index gets to 0, I have also tried using just < but the way I wrote the code it seems that it still goes beyond 0, I am not sure though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your index goes from `0, -1, -2...` whereas the length is either 0 or positive, once the negative indices go beyond the `-len(lst)` limit you get an out of bounds error.

```
>>> test = [1, 2, 3]
>>> test[-1]
3
>>> test[-2]
2
>>> test[-4]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>
    test[-4]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You could fix this by initializing the index variable to `len(lst) - 1` and iterating until 0.

```
index = len(test) - 1
while index >=0: 
    # Do Something
```

Or if you keep your `index` to `0`, then you could change your `while` loop to

```
while index > -len(fruit):
    # Do Something
```

**An Alternative** - You could use `for` loop on the reversed list here to iterate over the list in reverse. See the example

```
>>> testList = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in testList[::-1]:
        print i


3
2
1
```

`testList[::-1]` is [Python's Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation).

Comment: Actually, it should be `while index > -len(fruit)` to make it working. Your answer is a modified version of the asker's code :) I mean, your answer is all fine but in my opinion it'd be better to show the asker how to make his code work the way he meant it to be.

Comment: Yes. I could have changed that too. Added that as an alternative too. :)

Comment: Thank you, I changed index to `index = len(fruit)-1` and changed inside the loop `letter = index[fruit - 1]` to `letter = index[fruit]` and that fixed it.

Comment: Glad to hear. Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful. :)

Comment: You could mention about `fruit[::-1]` just in case OP does not know about it, or even using `reversed`.

Comment: @ersran9 : Added that as an alternative. Thanks. :)